# How to delete relational data in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables named `user` and `customer`.

Now how do I delete parent data when I delete child data?

Like when I run `$customer->delete();`
I want to delete from `user` where `user.id = customer.user_id`

**User model**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

**Customer model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Customer extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
        use SoftDeletingTrait;
        protected $table = 'customers';
        public $timestamps = true;
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

        public function User(){
            return $this->belongsTo('user','user_id','id');
        }
}
```

Comment: You can do `$customer->user()->delete();` before `$customer->delete();`

Comment: Is there any 'Triggers' available? same as SQL?

Comment: @Ramshad no There is no 'Triggers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) are available in `Eloquent` for this, for example:

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($customer) {
            // This will delete parent item
            // before it deletes child item
            $customer->user()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

So, when you'll call something like this:

```
Customer::find(1)->delete();
```

The parent item `User` will be deleted first then the child item `Customer` will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much I will give you feedback after testing. I have another question please review it after posting on it.